# Двухсвязная приоритетная очередь/список

Tags: java

Собственно суть вопроса в том, **где её найти** и **дать правильное название исходя из требований**, так как я не думаю что правильно указал что ищу.
Требования:
 1. Вставка/удаление в **начало и конец** очереди.
 2. Может сравнивать объекты реализуеющие интерфейс [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) для "запихивания" в очередь определенном порядке. Так же как в [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).
 3. Реализация не очень важна.

Comment: Я вроде понял, что это [DEPQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue) по моим требованиям и даже нашел класс, который [делает то, что нужно.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта структура данных называется [DEPQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue)